# Creating a schedule of Game Objects in Java

Tags: java, object, schedule

I'm in the process of developing a stat tracker for Baseball season. I'd like to be able to load an entire schedule ino the program, making each game a relatively simple object.

Creating the game object isn't an issue. What I'm wondering is, what's the best way to implement the schedule? I have, in the team class, an ArrayList schedule.

I need a way to load the schedule info from a text file, loop through it and create a game object for each line. If that's not the best way to create 162 objects efficiently, please let me know.

Cheers

EDIT:

The game class is really very simple:

```
public class Game implements Serializable{

Date gameDate;

Team team;

public int runsScored, runsAllowed;

public ArrayList<BallPlayer> lineup = new ArrayList<BallPlayer>();
public ArrayList<Pitcher> pitchers = new ArrayList<Pitcher>();
public Pitcher starter;

String opponent;
boolean homeAway;

boolean result;

public Game(Team gTeam, Pitcher gStarter, String gOpponent, String homeOrAway, Date gDate){

    this.team = gTeam;
    this.starter = gStarter;
    this.opponent = gOpponent;
    if(homeOrAway.equalsIgnoreCase("home")){this.homeAway = true;}
    this.runsScored = 0;
    this.runsAllowed = 0;
    gameDate = gDate;

}

public String getOpponent(){return opponent;}
public void setOpponent(String o){this.opponent = o;}

public boolean getHomeAway(){return homeAway;}
public void setHomeAway(String ho){if(ho.equalsIgnoreCase("home")){this.homeAway = true;}else{this.homeAway = false;}}
```

}

Comment: A lot depends on how your "Game" object looks like. Can you post your Game Class information?

Comment: Game class added. I can add the Team Class if you want... but it's about 500+ lines of code

Comment: You implement Serializable.. so read the games file and go back to your object using serializate? Could be an idea.. C# saves as XML, i don't know how Java save it.

Comment: Java saves it as a crazy txt file. I was thinking that, but the issue is creating 162 game objects from a real baseball schedule. Should I create 32 schedueles as .txt files and then have java loop through them, creating game objects as it goes along?

Comment: @user3166766 This might be more than what you want to do, but maybe JSON could be another data format... just a thought

Edit: I see Clayton already mentioned JSON.  Another Java library I've used is [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Comment: jDave if the answer below fulfills your question, click accept answer :)

Comment: I figured it out. Although your answer did help a lot. I wound up creating a few .txt files to store into the program. The idea was to be able to load pre-made schedules if you're following a professional team. Thank though! You were a huge help!

Comment: If you're following a little league team, well... you're gonna have to make that schedule of 22!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty general question but I thought I would give you some thoughts on how I would initially approach this.

For your models, you could start with something like this:

```
GameVO (id, home team id (TeamVO), away team id (TeamVO), location id, schedule_id)
TeamVO (id, mascot, name, hometown, etc.)
LocationVO (id, city, state, stadium name, etc.)
PlayerVO(id, position, fname, lname, number, team_id, array_of_stat_ids)
StatVO(id, game_id, player_id, base_hits, home_runs, rbi, strike_out, etc)
ScheduleVO(id, location_id, home_team_id, away_team_id, play_time)
```

For the text file, I would recommend becoming comfortable with [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).  Regular expressions allow you to read in strings of data and extract data based on the patterns that you specific. Your text file will either be a fixed-length text-file, comma separated values (CSV), or some other format (first make sure you understand how your data is structured).  Once you have identified the patterns that you want to extract, create your regex to match on every line and extract the appropriate values.  Here is a good place to practice with your [Regex](http://regexpal.com/)

Finally, when seriallizing your objects take a look at seriallizers like [XStream for .NET](https://code.google.com/p/xstream-dot-net/).  I liked the Java version of this library as it allows you to quickly turn java objects into XML/json and back again.

Comment: I was hoping not to work with Regular Expressions (They drive me nuts). What I was hoping I could do was copy and paste a team schedule from espn, mlb or something like that, and make a text file out of that, and have java create game files from that text file. is it possible to make a loop and do the same task?

Comment: Another approach would be to do web scraping.  Extract the content directly from the sports website with your application, and convert that into a game object.

Comment: Clayton... how can I do that?! That sounds cool as all goshness!

Comment: jDave is here a nice blog post by Adrian where he demonstrates scraping .  http://adrianlucathomas.blogspot.com/2013/02/starters-guide-to-web-scraping-with.html

Comment: Also jDave...I feel your pain about regexp, but trust me.  If you spend a few hours taking the time to learn them, life becomes so much different!  Here was my progression to learning regexp casually over a few weeks:

Clueless -> Angry and Confused -> Semicapable-> Confident but wildly overusing them -> And finally, the ideal state: a powerful tool in my belt.  

Take some time and learn them, they can save your hide (just don't go crazy and overuse them when you learn to love them)!